# What is the equivalent of Chrome's Alt+Enter in the address bar for Firefox?

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, google-chrome

In Chrome, if I want to duplicate the current page in a new tab, I highlight the address bar and click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  What's the equivalent keyboard shortcut for Firefox?

I'm currently on a Mac with Firefox 14.0.1.  I will test on Windows and Ubuntu later to see if it works there.

Comment: `Opt-Return` (i.e. `Alt-Enter` in Mac terminology) works like a charm on OS X Mountain Lion with Firefox 12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on my Firefox install (v14.01) works exactly the same as it does in Chrome. Perhaps you need to upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

The same shortcut works on the Firefox 13 and according to my information it will work on older versions as well. Just highlight the address bar and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and you will get the dupe tab of the current one.

Also there is an [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/duplicate-tab/) available for this for Firefox which can open the duplicate tab.